# Paredit Wrap Round command not bound to M-(

Tags: emacs, paredit

I'm using Paredit and was studying the cheatsheet. The source and documentation suggest that `M-(` should trigger `paredit-wrap-round` but on my system when I use `C-h k M-(` to find the keybinding for M-( I get:

```
M-( runs the command paredit-backward-slurp-sexp, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `paredit.el'.

It is bound to <C-M-left>, C-(, ESC <C-left>, M-(.

...
```

How do I find out what is rebinding `M-(` to `paredit-backward-slurp-sexp` and make it back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external tool: [describe-key-and-map-briefly](https://github.com/emacsmirror/nxhtml/blob/master/util/ourcomments-util.el) to find out which keymap the definition is coming from, then advice around `define-key` to log `load-file-name` to show where the guilty call is coming from.

Before all that, you probably want to make sure your version of paredit isn't doing anything weird by using `emacs -Q` and loading just paredit and checking the bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I load paredit after opening `emacs -Q`? Without the rest of my load setup I'm not sure how to load it.

Comment: that entirely depends on your setup.